# How can I add these two VBA Codes together?

Tags: excel, vba, range

'Replacing the "B8" Range from this code:

```
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    Set MainPage = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With IE
            .Visible = True
            .Navigate MainPage.Range("B8").Hyperlinks(1).Address
            Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        End With
```

Replacing it with this code below:

```
Sheets("sheet1").Select
rowNum = Range("B1").Value
   Range(Cells(rowNum, 2), Cells(rowNum, 2)).Select
```

This code determines the cell address. I would like this code to replace the Range("B8") where I .navigate to a hyperlink.

I'm new to VBA and struggling to do this.

Comment: Hi - could you clarify: "I would like this code to replace the Range("B8")" - replace it with what? Thanks, will try to help

Comment: wouldn't you just change the "B8" to "B1" (or where ever you want it to go)?

Comment: Hi @JohnnieL I have updated my question. Please let me know if it makes more sense now.

Comment: @sous2817  The cell "B1" contains a Number value that determines the row number. This is used so that whenever n change that number in cell "B1" the outcome of my second code produces a new Range and this range should be used where "B8" is in my code on top. Hope that make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to use the selected cell as the parameter for your `.navigate`

The first part of code can be

```
Sheets("sheet1").Activate
rowNum = Range("B1").Value
' The original code creates a range that starts and ends at the same place 
' so the Range(...) i dont think is needed

Cells(rowNum, 2).Select
```

then the call just becomes

```
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate ActiveCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    End With
```

is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes exactly. Thank you. This worked well!

Comment: Thanks @AlmóSter glad it helped - maybe you could mark the answer/up vote it? thanks

Comment: Yes I will. Just won't count yet I'm a newbie

Answer (score 0):

My stab at it is to avoid using .Select and .Activate all together as that has a high likelihood of not being what you think it is depending on upstream and downstream code.

If I'm following what you're after this should work:

```
Sub test()
   Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
   Set MainPage = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
   
    With MainPage
        rowNum = .Range("B1").Value
        someNum = .Range(rowNum, 2).Value
    End With
    
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate MainPage.Range("B" & someNum).Hyperlinks(1).Address
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

It can be further simplified, but this way you can see what's happening a bit more cleanly.  As you get more experience and learn the language, you'll be able to condense the code without too much trouble.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you appreciate it! I have used @johnnieL code. But yes this is the same and would also work as good. VBA is really fun when things work out:)

Comment: @AlmóSter Glad you found some code that works.  Just a warning to be careful when relying on .Activating or .Selecting cells because it may not always be reliable.